# What are the benefits of not supporting UDP in cloud network? (thinking of Windows Azure case)

Tags: networking, azure, udp, cloud

Azure, Rackspace and Amazon do handle UDP, but GAE (the most similar to Azure) does not.

I am wondering what are the expected benefits of this restriction. Does it help fine-tuning the network? Does it ease the load balancing? Does is help to secure the network?

Comment: Just out of interest, why do you need UDP? What's the use case?

Comment: BTW, you can add your vote to add the feature here: http://www.mygreatwindowsazureidea.com/forums/34192-windows-azure-feature-voting/suggestions/400782-udp-endpoints

Comment: @Richard, accessing a (non-cloud) Microsoft SQL Server requires UDP, unless a specific configuration is applied. Then, before I genuinely interested in the answer before requesting UDP. It might not be worth the cost for the cloud as a whole.

Comment: You can connect to SQL Server over TCP. In fact using PortBridge I have successfully connected an application running on Azure to a local SQL Server behind a firewall. http://vasters.com/clemensv/2009/11/18/Port+Bridge.aspx

Comment: Edited to correct the fact that Azure does support UDP.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the reason is that UDP traffic does not have a defined lifetime nor a defined packet to packet relationship.  This makes it hard to load balance and hard to manage - when you don't know how long to hold the path open you end up using timers, this is a problem for some NAT implementations too.

Comment: My answer was a bit thin so I thought I should elaborate.  TCP is a connection based protocol that has a handshake mechanism to open and close connections.  The start of a TCP connection is defined clearly in the transmitted packets, as is the end.  UDP is connectionless so there is no relationship (at the UDP level) between one packet and the next.  You need to examine the content and know how to decode the enclosed protocol to know what sequence of packets to expect and when a conversation is done.  Most devices passing UDP just use timers to measure connection lifetime, this does not scale.

Comment: I abandoned using azure because I wanted to use it as a DNS server, DNS is generally UDP based so the service was/is of no use to me.

Answer (score 1):

There's another angle not really explored here so far.  UDP traffic is also a huge source of security problems, specifically DDoS attacks.

By blocking all UDP traffic, Azure can more effectively mitigate these attacks.  Nearly all large bandwidth attacks, which are by far the hardest to deal with, are Amplification Attacks of some sort and most often UDP based.  Allowing that traffic past the border of the network greatly improves the likelihood of service disruption, regardless of QoS sureties.

A second facet to that same story is that by blocking UDP they prevent people from hosting insecure DNS servers and thus prevent Azure from being the source of these large scale amplification attacks.  This is actually a very good thing for the internet overall, as I'd think the connectivity of Azure's data centers are significant.  To contrast this I've had servers in AWS send non stop UDP attacks to our datacenter for months on end, and could not successfully get the abuse team to respond to it.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes to my mind is that maybe they wanted to avoid their cloud being accessed through an unreliable transport protocol.

Along with scalability, reliability is one of the key aspects in Azure. For example Sql Azure and Azure Storage data is always replicated in at least three places and roles with at least two instances have a 99.95% uptime in their SLA.

Of course, despite its partial unreliability, UDP has its use cases, some of them enumerated in the comments from the feature voting [site](http://www.mygreatwindowsazureidea.com/forums/34192-windows-azure-feature-voting/suggestions/400782-udp-endpoints), but maybe those use cases are not a target for the Azure platform.